# ANSI C: Couldn't get strcmp to work

Tags: c

I use Pocket C++ for ANSI C.  I try to get `strcmp()` to work in my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str1 = 'C';
  char str2[3] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
  int ret;

  ret = strcmp(str1, str2[3]);

  if (ret == 0) {
      printf("The are equal");
  } else {
      printf("They are not equal");
  }

  return(0);
}
```

I got an error:

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

along with other errors. Then I try to change variable: 
`char const * var = 'C';` or `const char * var = 'C';`

It still doesn't work, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Yo compare characters == is enough. strcmp is for strings (which are char* and delimited with ")

Comment: [`int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp) expects 2 strings (`char` pointers or `char *`), while you are passing simple `char`s.

Comment: Note, however, that `&str` **will not suffice** as a char pointer because [null termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) is required.

Answer (score 1):

> what did I do wrong?

**You are sending in the wrong arguments to [`strcmp()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) function**. *and also you are* **Accessing an array out of bounds**.

I think you have a misunderstanding of what the [`strcmp()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) function does. It does not compare two characters but instead, it compare two strings(character arrays with null terminating character).

If you just want to compare two strings then no function is required, just use the `==` operator this way:

```
ret = (str1 == str2[2]);

if (ret == 1) 
{
   printf("The are equal");
} 
else 
{
  printf("They are not equal");
}
```

---

So now, **when to use the `strcmp()` function?**

Use it when you want to compare two(character arrays which end with null terminating character) strings this way:

```
char str1[10] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
char str2[10] = "abc";    //here automatically null character is provided at the end
int ret;

ret = strcmp(str1 ,str2);

if (ret == 0) 
{
   printf("The are equal");
} 
else 
{
  printf("They are not equal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the strcmp function in the C Language is:

int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

Parameters or Arguments:
s1 = An array to compare.
s2 = An array to compare.

```
Return Value------Remarks
1. 0--------------if both strings are identical (equal)
2. negative -------if the ASCII value of the first unmatched character is less than second.
3. positive integer---if the ASCII value of the first unmatched character is greater than second.
```

You are comparing a character variable with a character array. So modify that.